# PHP shopping cart display issue

Tags: php, shopping-cart

When creating a shopping cart for my website, I have add and remove functions for individual products. When I add a product it adds it to a new row in the table, not the current row.

Here is the code for adding and removing products:

```
function addproduct($product_id, $product_qty){

$q = "SELECT p_name FROM Product WHERE product_id = $product_id LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$product_name = $row['p_name']; //get the product name from product id because it is better to display name than id in the cart
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])){  //if shopping cart is not empty
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if (array_key_exists($product_name, $cart)){ //if the product exists, update                        quantity
        $cart[$product_name] += $product_qty;
    }
    else {  //otherwise, add new product-quantity pair to the array
        $cart[$product_name] = $product_qty;
    }
$_SESSION['cart'] = $cart; //write the updated array back to session variable
}
else { //if shopping cart is empty
    $cart = array($product_name=>$product_qty); //add product and quantity to the                           shopping cart
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart; //write the updated array back
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
function deleteproduct($product_id, $product_qty){
$q = "SELECT p_name FROM Product WHERE product_id = $product_id LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$product_name = $row['p_name'];
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])){ //if shopping cart is not empty
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if (array_key_exists($product_name, $cart)){ //if product exists, update quantity
        $cart[$product_name] -= $product_qty;
        if ($cart[$product_name] == 0){ //if the qty 0, delete key
            unset($cart[$product_name]);
        }
    }
    else { //exception
        echo "<p>Error1</p>";
    }
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart; //write array back to session variable
} else {
    echo "<p>Error2</p>";
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: We don't need to see the deleteproduct in that code. Can you give examples of $product_name? Also you're doing a few things twice when, by changing your ifs you can do just once.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is how i stop another row being added to the table when I add an addtional quantity of an item?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe cut this

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])){  //if shopping cart is not empty
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if (array_key_exists($product_name, $cart)){ //if the product exists, update                        quantity
        $cart[$product_name] += $product_qty;
    }
    else {  //otherwise, add new product-quantity pair to the array
        $cart[$product_name] = $product_qty;
    }
$_SESSION['cart'] = $cart; //write the updated array back to session variable
}
else { //if shopping cart is empty
    $cart = array($product_name=>$product_qty); //add product and quantity to the                           shopping cart
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart; //write the updated array back
}
```

down to three lines and let me know if it still doesn't work.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) $_SESSION['cart']=array();
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_name])) $_SESSION['cart'][$product_name]=$product_qty;
else $_SESSION['cart'][$product_name]+=$product_qty;
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but the issue that I'm having is still there